# Java create file in Eclipse not creating nor deleting

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to learn java with the book "Java for Dummies" with Eclipse.

Now I have to learn how to create files and deleting them.

- I tried multiple statement but none of them work.
- I tried changing the permissions with no effect.
- Also, when I manually create the file, the code won't delete it.

Hopefully you guys can help. I updated Eclipse and I am using JDK 14.0.1.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Path path = Paths.get("G:\\Users\\Gerard\\eclipse-workspace\\Java for dummies 2\\");
        File evidence = new File(path +"\\cookedBooks.txt");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {  
            out.println("Looking for " + evidence.getCanonicalPath());
            } 
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {  e.printStackTrace();}
            char reply;do {
                out.print("Delete evidence? (y/n) ");
                reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
                } 

        while (reply != 'y' && reply != 'n'); 
            if (reply == 'y') { 
                    out.println("Okay, here goes...");
                    evidence.delete();
                    out.println("The evidence has been deleted.");
                } 
            else { 
                    out.println("Sorry, buddy. Just asking.");
                }      
        keyboard.close();   
        }
    }
```

The book uses:

```java
import java.io.File;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeleteEvidence {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File evidence = new File("cookedBooks.txt");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char reply;
        do {
            out.print("Delete evidence? (y/n) ");
            reply = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

console output for y and n
Looking for G:\Users\Gerard\eclipse-workspace\Java for dummies 2\cookedBooks.txt
Delete evidence? (y/n)
y
Okay, here goes...
The evidence has been deleted.

Looking for G:\Users\Gerard\eclipse-workspace\Java for dummies 2\cookedBooks.txt
Delete evidence? (y/n)
n
Sorry, buddy. Just asking.

no errors

Comment: I corrected the tag: [tag:java] !== javascript

Comment: Just a quick tip, use [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) to build a path instead of concatenating a separator. It is much safer.

Comment: Is there any program output in Eclipse's console window?

Comment: Looking for G:\Users\Gerard\eclipse-workspace\Java for dummies 2\cookedBooks.txt
Delete evidence? (y/n) y
Okay, here goes...
The evidence has been deleted.  this is the console output

Comment: Add the full output to the OP - it is part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to help guys. today i reinstalled and updated eclipse and now it can delete.